# Finding and converting subnet mask to CIDR in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list containing hundreds of ip addresses and masks in this format:

```
['10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0', '10.10.20.0/255.255.255.192']
```

I would like to convert this list to this format:

```
['10.10.10.0/24', '10.10.20.0/26']
```

Here is my code:

```
# List already containing all ip/mask (format: 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0') shown above
print ip_mask_list
#hardcoded mask for testing
netmask = "255.255.248.0"
#convert mask to CIDR
cidr = sum([bin(int(x)).count('1') for x in netmask.split('.')])
print cidr  # prints 21
```

I can convert a mask to CIDR but how would I do it so instead of passing hardcoded netmask variable, I can pass `ip_mask_list` and it goes thru all masks and convert the to CIDR as shown above.  Maybe create a next list where all `255.x.x.x` are converted to `/xx`.

Thanks

Damon

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
s = ['10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0', '10.10.20.0/255.255.255.192']
final_ips = ['{}/{}'.format(a, sum([bin(int(x)).count('1') for x in b.split('.')])) for a, b in map(lambda x:re.findall('[\d\.]+', x), s)]
```

Output:

```
['10.10.10.0/24', '10.10.20.0/26']
```

Comment: What ??? Those are just sample data. OP wants a solution for **all** mask.

Comment: @liliscent Thank you for the clarification. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: In fact, there are at most 24 possible network masks. It would be much faster to just create a small dict. But anyway, your solution works...

Answer (score 0):

This one splits the original IP address in an IP and a mask part. The IP Address is used as before while the `cidr_suffix` is calculated based on the number of set bits in the `ip_mask`.

```
ips = ['10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0', '10.10.20.0/255.255.255.192']

def append_cidr_suffix(full_ip):
    address_and_mask = full_ip.split('/')
    prefix = address_and_mask[0]
    ip_mask = address_and_mask[1]

    suffix = sum(bin(int(sub_part)).count('1') for sub_part in ip_mask.split('.'))   

    return prefix + '/' + str(suffix)

cidr_ips = [append_cidr_suffix(i) for i in ips]
```

Comment: Thanks, is it faster than the first solution?